# Win 8 App cant connect to web service but the exe file is connected

Tags: winrt-xaml, windows-firewall

My Application is Win8App , It was working in All our PCs win 8.0/8.1 , now some of these PCs giving Error Msg, and the other is working  :

- Error Msg : There was no endpoint listening at that could accept the message. this is often caused by an incorrect
- If i connect this web service from windows Application (EXE) it will work .
- If we run Fiddler the application will work.
- If we shutdown the firewall from the services list , the App will work .
- If we remove the PC from the domain and work as workgroup the application will work .
- If we activate Firewall outbound logs we can see that firewall was deny to send request to web service , even  if we add a role to allow this port .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now i resolved , Just tick on Private Networks (Client & Server) in cabibilities